# Nested RecyclerViews MVP implementation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mvp

I want to make an app that has a vertical `RecyclerView` with nested horizontal `RecyclerView`s. I don't understand how to use properly an MVP pattern in such case. MVP "rule" says that it should be only one View for a screen.

[image]

My `View` interface:

```
public interface ViewLayer {
    void showProductsInCategory(int categoryId, List<ProductModel> productList, PresenterLayer presenter);

    void showCategories(List<CategoryModel> categoryItemList, PresenterLayer presenter);
}
```

Presenter:

```
public interface PresenterLayer {
    void onViewReady();
}
```

Model:

```
public interface InteractorLayer {
    void getProducts(int categoryId);

    void getCategories();
}
```

Model listener interface:

```
public interface InteractorListener {
    void onProductsLoaded(int id, List<ProductModel> products);

    void onCategoriesLoaded(List<CategoryModel> categories);
}
```

CategoryModel:

```
public class CategoryModel {
    private String categoryName;
    private List<ProductModel> productList;

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public List<ProductModel> getProductList() {
        return productList;
    }

    public void setProductList(List<ProductModel> productList) {
        this.productList = productList;
    }
}
```

So I have to select each nested `RecyclerView` by `categoryId` to add the data to their adapter. Can I create separate Model-View-Presenter interfaces for every horizontal `RecyclerView`?

**UPD:**

Step by step

1) `MainActivity.onCreate` calls `presenter.onViewReady()`

2) Presenter calls `interactorLayer.getCategories()`

3) Model calls `InteractorListener.onCategoriesLoaded(List<CategoryModel> categories)`

4) Presenter calls `ViewLayer`(`MainActivity`) `showCategories(List<CategoryModel> categoryItemList, PresenterLayer presenter)`

5) `MainActivity` sets that `categoryItemList` to the outer `RecyclerView`'s adapter. Now each categoryItem has `null` `productList`

6) In the method `onCategoriesLoaded(...)` after `ViewLayer.showCategories(...)` Presenter calls Model's `InteractorLayer.getProducts(i)` in the cycle for each Category

7) After any `productList` loaded `Presenter` calls `ViewLayer`'s `showProductsInCategory(...)`

8) `MainActivity` gets the `Adapter` of the main `RecyclerView`, gets a Category item and sets the `productList` for it.

9) `MainActivity` calls `Adapter`'s `notifyDataSetChanged()`

10) The inner `RecyclerView` sets new `productList` when `onBinding` calls

I think its very complicated. What can I do with that?

**UPD 03/24/2017**

Source code: https://github.com/Lex74/ProductsShop

Comment: Maybe I have a different concept of how to implement MVP, so could you share how you do it for just the "outer" RecyclerView? (And is it really a good idea to name the interface "View" ? )

Comment: See my updated post, please. I added some code and explanations. See step 5 for outer RecyclerView.

Comment: A very interesting question :) I'll write a small sample app in order to find out what to call exactly as soon as a ProductList is loaded, but I think this will have to wait until next weekend.

Comment: Weekend is coming... ;) Here my [repo](https://github.com/Lex74/ProductsShop) You can use my code. There is a simple project just for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the repo - it was really helpful for understanding your situation. I edited my answer and started changing the code, but I'm not yet finished (and some weekends somehow are shorter than others). Maybe it's not a good idea anyway to add details to the already lengthy answer, so I think I'll try to somehow upload the changes to Github - this is as good a time as any to learn how to use it ;-)

Comment: I've managed to upload part of my version of your app to [https://github.com/0X0nosugar/NestedRecyclerViewMVP](https://github.com/0X0nosugar/NestedRecyclerViewMVP).

Comment: @0X0nosugar Try to load source code instead of zip. It's more convenient) You can upload it from Android Studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd like to state that I don't think of myself as a MVP guru, rather as someone who's striving to understand the pattern,

My favourite MVP reference: [The Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) from Uncle Bob's blog

According to this blog post, there is something called **The Dependency Rule**:

> ...*source code dependencies* can only point inwards. Nothing in an inner circle can know anything at all about something in an outer circle...

For example, the `Presenter` class does not need to know anything about `RecyclerView` or `RecyclerView.Adapter`. It needs some `interface` to pass information to the outer layer.

The methods of the `interface` depend on the use case: with a `List`, one would like to be able to

pass a reference to the whole data `List` (`showCategories()`)

refresh single list items (`showProductsInCategory()`)

So I think the Dependency Rule says, that the `ViewLayer` interface has to offer methods which satisfy the needs of the [**Model** layer and the] **Presenter** layer. As a **Presenter**, I simply don't care whether the **View** out there is a `ListView` or maybe not a `View` at all but rather some combination of sound and vibration signals.

On the other hand, it seems to be perfectly ok for a `View` class to know the name (and methods of) its `Presenter` class, so maybe the `PresenterLayer` interface is no must-have.

It's entirely up to the **View** how the data will be offered to the user. A nested `View` structure still is just a complicated `View`. So I dont' think one needs to provide nested `interface`s.

In some cases with nested `List`s, the `Presenter` might need a method to update an item of the inner `List`, something like `showSingleProductInCategory(ProductModel product, int categoryPosition, int productPosition)`.

Another interesting question: who keeps (and may modify) the data? In my opinion, the **Presenter** is responsible for the data, and it should only pass a reference to the data into the **View** layer or notify it of changes. An Adapter should not have the right to modify the original data list, a Presenter should never have to ask the Adapter "how many items are there?" and I don't really like the idea of two separate data lists. The names of the various notify... methods seem to indicate that I'm on the right track there.

This means `Presenter` will always hold on to the original data `List`. If data changes, the `Presenter` will update its data (may be `clear()` and "copy the new items", may also be more fine-grained, depending on what `ProductLoader` is offering) Afterwards, `Presenter` will notify the `Adapter` via the `ViewLayer` interface.

Link to a [zip file with the modified Java classes](https://github.com/0X0nosugar/NestedRecyclerViewMVP)

**EDIT**

Somehow I doubt that "one **View** for one screen" will work well for Android. Imagine the typical Master-Detail situation. If the screen is large, you will want to use the space and show both `Fragment`s at once.

So if you have one **View** (and one **Presenter**) per `Fragment`, everything will work for all types of screens. It's up to the `Activity` to manage the `Fragment`s depending on the screen size.

I've already explained that I like to have the `Adapter` of some `ListView` or `RecyclerView` implement the `interface` which is required as a callback for the `Presenter`. (All the `Fragment` in its role as callback could do would be to pass the information on to the `Adapter`anyway)

On the other hand, a `Fragment` may well contain several groups of data. Some of them may be somehow related (like all the songs by one particular artist), others (all those ads...) rather not. The **Presenter** needs methods to tell the **View** what to show to the user: one method for the artist, one for the advertisement etc.

So if I had an app with a handful of `Fragment`s, the `interface` would contain methods like

```
void showAdvertisement(AdObject ad);
void showArtistInfo(Artist artist);
```

... and the `Presenter` would expect some class implementing this specific `interface` in its `Constructor`. (Plus the `Adapter` for the songs), and I'd have the `Fragment` implement the `interface` for all the non-collection data.

In a project with several apps, one might consider using generic `interface`s 
(one for any kind of detail information, one for collections). Then one would have a method `showData(T data)`, and the `Presenter` in the example above would expect one callback for the advertisement and one for the artist info:

```
MyPlaylistPresenter (DetailInterface<AdObject> adCallback, DetailInterface<Artist> artistCallback, CollectionInterface<Song> songsCallback){...}
```

and then in the `Fragment` one would write:

```
MyPlaylistPresenter presenter = new MyPlaylistPresenter(this, this, adapter);
```

A little bit like Lego :), but all in all less `interface` classes. And methods which do basically the same thing have the same name all over the project, so I think it contributes to maintainability.

Now about your other question:

If your app has a **Model** on the client side, then I think you're right. 
On the other hand, there are projects where the **Model** is part of the backend. Then the **Presenter** would be the logical choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for such interesting approach! But what if MainActivity will have more views? Should it implements ViewLayer?

Comment: @Alexander L. - Well, if my app had a handful of Fragments or Activities, I think one would like to have one interface per Fragment/Activity. But imagine a project with several apps and more than twenty Fragments... I'd like to edit my answer and explain my approach, but this will have to wait some days (again). For now, thank you for your interest and for the great question, not least the repo :)

Comment: One more question) Is it OK, that Presenter holds List? List is a data, isn't it should be inside of Model?

Comment: @Alexander L. - I edited my answer. And I promise to learn how to use Git in Android Studio :)